# Jaspersoft float number pattern

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

Im using Jaspersoft Studio to design my reports and JasperReports Server to publish them for my php web application.

In one of my reports it contains some float numbers displayed in the format 103.12 but i want it to be displayed like this: `103,12` and when it reaches 5 digits like this `50 000,14`.

After some reading i tried to set the local to french but nothing changed.
And when i change the pattern in the jasperstudio to `# ###,00` i get this :

[image]

and for the old pattern `#,###.00`  that comes by default in the jasperstudio i get this :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Analysis**

We dealt with this as well. The locale which is being set in the JasperReports server login page is just for the admin UI, *not* for the report generation.

**Solution**

If you want to have a different locale set on your server, you need to set it in the JasperReports server config in `/jasperreport-path/apache-tomcat/bin/setenv.sh` (add it into one of those `JAVA_OPTS`):

```
-Duser.language=FR -Duser.country=FR
```

Now all locale-specific settings will be correctly configured and putting `#,###.00` as a pattern for the field will be translated to your locale format by default in the server. So for the french format would be displayed like this: `1 000,12`.

Comment: for the pattern it didn't work it shows me for 107533.123  something like 10,72,02 that's why i wanted to use internationalization, because at least the dot  '.' will be changed to  comma ',' , but it didn't worked even with adding set JAVA_OPTS=--JvmMs 1024 --JvmMx 2048 --JvmSs 2 -Duser.language=FR -Duser.country=FR %JAVA_OPTS%

Comment: Sorry, I didn't completely understand your comment. It is shown separated by commas? Maybe the pattern has to use a dot and no comma.

Comment: yes, i think that too. hte pattern can be changed that's why that's why they recommand to change the local of the report but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Still not clear what the status of your question is right now. Can you update your question with screenshots of the current behaviour and your pattern settings? How did it look before adding the additional parameters? Any outputs in the Jasper log files? Please edit the question accordingly.